# How do I make my own true / false return function?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make my own function which performs in a similar manner to the following actual code.. ie

```
if(mysql_num_rows($res) == FALSE) {

  // DO SOMETHING BECAUSE THERE ARE NO RESULTS

}
```

In my code, i'm repeating an SQL statement a few times around the place, and if there are results, then I go ahead and do stuff.

What I'd like to do is create my own FALSE return in my own function ie

```
if(my_special_function($variable) == FALSE) {

    // DO STUFF

}
```

Is this as simple as in my special function having something like...

```
function my_special_function($variable) {

   $sql = 'SELECT field FROM table WHERE something=$variable';
   $res = mysql_query($sql);

   if(mysql_num_rows($res) == FALSE) {

     return FALSE;

   } else {

     return TRUE;

   }
}
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your special function even simpler:

```
function my_special_function($variable)
{
   $sql = "SELECT field FROM table WHERE something='{$variable}'";
   $res = mysql_query($sql);
   return mysql_num_rows($res) > 0;
}
```

Comment: I think that's most simple, but I would use type-casting while returning: `return (boolean)mysql_num_rows($res)`

Comment: faileN: What would be the advantage?

Answer (score 1):

I can see a few problems.

Variable interpolation does not happen in single quotes, also its advisable to not to substitute variable directly into queries.

```
   $sql = 'SELECT field FROM table WHERE something=$variable';
```

should be

```
   $sql = 'SELECT field FROM table WHERE something='.mysql_real_escape_string($variable);
```

[`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) returns `false` when there is a problem, say when its parameter is not a valid `resource`. If you really want to check the case of "no rows returned" you need to check its value for `0`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is all for a function. Why don't you try such things first before asking whether it works or not?

You should add additional error checking for `mysql_query` and replace `$sql = 'SELECT field FROM table WHERE something=$variable';` by:

```
$sql = 'SELECT field FROM table WHERE something='.$variable;
```

Comment: I guess I could have tried I just didn't know if this was a hack or considered proper coding. I have invented my own way of doing things in the past without checking in with good programmers like yourself only to find it was a security risk or it only worked because of a bug in the PHP or something like that. Hence I run through new things here as what is obvious to you guys, isn't that obvious to me. Cheers!!

Comment: This are basic language constructs. You should get familiar with them. Just to note, `if(somefunc() == FALSE)` is the same as `if(!somefunc())`. The PHP Manual has a [nice table about comparing types](http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

Answer (score 1):

I'd revise it a bit

```
function my_special_function($variable) {
   $sql = "SELECT field FROM table WHERE something=$variable";
   $res = mysql_query($sql);

   if(mysql_num_rows($res)) {
     return TRUE;
   }
   return FALSE;
}
```

### Changes

1. No need for the else { ... } as if the if evaluation is true, it won't go any further, if it isn't, then `FALSE` is returned.
2. Changed the `if` statement to `if(mysql_num_rows($res))` as `mysql_num_rows()` will return FALSE on failure, and a number on everything else. So, if there's 0 affected rows, or an error you won't get the return `TRUE`.
3. Inside your $sql variable you had single quotes, the literal `$variable` would be passed rather than what was passed to the function

Comment: if you use `return mysql_num_rows($res) > 0;` you don't need any if statement ;-)

Comment: Yeah, but even though anything besides 0/false equates to true, the OP may want the actual return value of TRUE

Comment: I think this does return the value of TRUE. It does not return the number of rows. It returns either TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: Robert guessed right. Returning TRUE is on the cards!! Although both methods rock.

Comment: Mine returns TRUE too... that's what the discussion above is about.